# Attempting to produce dynamic picklist options

Tags: apex

I am using the following class as an extension for a Visualforce page for an object called Policy_Profile__c. I am creating the record. It is meant to query the Vendor__c field of the record being created and return with the names of all of the records related to it through the Vendor_Products__r relationship.

But a couple things are happening :

1) It is not returning a value for the accountid string which is referring to the Vendor__c field. 
2) It is producing the following error when I am saving the record :

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page contractoverviewnew: Class.ContractOverviewNew.save: line 82, column 1

Class.ContractOverviewNew.save: line 82, column 1
```

I'm not sure why it's producing that error. It may be because it is attempting to query "None" (the default value) since I am unable to produce options.

Here is the Apex class :

```
public class PolicyProfileVFControllerEdit
{
private final Policy_Profile__c main;
public String rightOptionsHidden { get; set; }
public String leftOptionsHidden { get; set; }
public String selectedMulPickKeyTech{get;set;} 
public string lookupid{get;set;}
public String message { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> options { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> selectedSubs2 { get; set; }
public String selectedItems { get; set; }
public String mainid {get;set;}
public String coid {get;set;}    
    public PolicyProfileVFControllerEdit(apexpages.standardcontroller controller)
        {
        this.main = (Policy_Profile__c) controller.getRecord();
        }

    public pageReference  execute()
        {
        return null;
        }

    public list<selectoption> getitems()
        {
        lookupid=main.Vendor__c;
        mainid=main.id;
        //Set<String> selectedItems = new Set<String>();
        selectedItems=main.Products_Affected3__c;
        coid = main.id;

        selectedMulPickKeyTech=main.Products_Affected3__c;
        selectedMulPickKeyTech=selectedMulPickKeyTech.replace('[','');                
        selectedMulPickKeyTech=selectedMulPickKeyTech.replace(']','');

        String[] selectedvalues = selectedMulPickKeyTech.split(',');

        selectedSubs2 = new list<SelectOption>();
        for (String selectedvalue: selectedvalues) 
            {
            selectedSubs2.add(new SelectOption(selectedvalue,selectedvalue));
            }

        List<selectoption> options= new list<selectoption>();
            if(lookupid != null)
            {
            Vendor_Profile__c a =[select name , (select name from Vendor_Products__r) from Vendor_Profile__c where id =:lookupid];
                for(Vendor_Product__c s : a.Vendor_Products__r)
                    {
                        //check that selected items dont already contain the keys
                        if(!selectedItems.contains(s.name))
                    options.add(new SelectOption(s.name,s.name));
                    }
            }
            else
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','None'));
            return options;
        }

    public PageReference save()
        {
        message = null ;       
        Boolean first = true;
           for ( SelectOption so : selectedSubs2 ) 
            {
                if (first) 
                    {
                    message = message ;
                    }
                    message = message + ', ' + so.getValue() ;
                    first = false;
            }        
                message = message.removeStart('null, ');
                message = message.normalizeSpace();
                message = '['+message+']';
                main.Products_Affected3__c=message;

        update main;

      PageReference pr = new PageReference('/a7w/o');

          pr.setRedirect(true);
          return pr;

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an Assert statement after the query in line 28 _System.Assert(contract!=null)_ and run again. I believe that the query is returning nothing and your contract is set to null. This causes the issue on line 82

Comment: you should be getting the same error when you call the execute method, as manjit_singh pointed your contract query is null, either you are not providing  Policy_Profile__c Id in the URL or there is no Policy_Profile__c matching the ID

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your input @Rao and manjit_singh. I have decided to abandon that code. I have some other code which works as long as Products_Affected3__c is populated. I've updated my initial post with that code. I am just having problems accounting for a blank Products_Affected3__c. Can you see where I could account for that ?